# Gitlab installation - Ruby rail error

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, gitlab

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10 and was updating my Gitlab from 6.8 to 7 and everything went wrong. Now I have removed it and is trying to install a new version but ran into a problem with Ruby.

When I try install it

> $ sudo apt install gitlab

I get an error after some time:

> Could not find gem 'rails (>= 4.2.7.1, ~> 4.2.7)' in any of the gem sources
>   listed in your Gemfile.

I have tried to run

> $ sudo gem install rails

but this gives me another error:

> ERROR:  Error installing rails:
>           activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.

I don't know what to do now...

---

I have started all over... Removed gitlab* and postgresql. Rebooted and installed gitlab again. Now I got another error:

> Could not find gem 'pg (~> 0.18.2)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.

Tried to install pg manually:

> $ sudo gem install pg 
>   Successfully installed pg-0.20.0

But still sudo apt upgrade gives the same error: "Could not find gem 'pg'

Comment: What is your Ruby version?

Comment: I have version 2.1.2p95

Comment: Activesupport requires a version >= 2.2.2, Try updating your Ruby

Comment: I have uninstalled it all again and was trying to reinstall - but got another error: "Could not find gem 'pg'".... Stalled again! :-(

Comment: `gem install pg`

Comment: See original message, Already tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up! I reinstalled the Linux server with the Linux LTS version and used the Omnibus package installation..

Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing a hidden dependency.  Try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Comment: I already tried that: libpq-dev is already the newest version (9.5.6-0ubuntu0.16.10).